# Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am using a deep reinforcement learning approach to navigate an agent from one initial point to goal point. There are also other agents and obstacles in the scene.

Μy first problem is what **input the neural network** will have.

Τhese are the elements I know in the initial scene:

1. Position and the initial velocity for the agent.
2. Position for other agents
3. Position of obstacles

In other cases, I have read that the input to the neural network is an image(probably sensors are used), but in my case I do not want to use visual sensors.

2.I found that in Reinforcement learning algorithms, the dataset is not pregenerated, but we simulate the data at training time.

I did not found how I can create the dataset make use of the 3 elements I mentioned above.

Comment: This question is probably a bit too broad to answer here. I suggest you take a look at other example in the OpenAI Gym: https://gym.openai.com

Answer (score 1):

1. Input to neural network: can be any features which you think will aid in your agent making decision
2. You can simulate the data by generating reward for each action. The reward can be positive or negative and it will act as the target to the neural network. After many episodes of training, your agent will learn to take the action with the high returns in reward.